# Aosp Build Error

Tags: android, perl, android-source

im trying to build android Os  in Mac OS 
after  i finsih all the steps when im trying to execute make command 
make -j4

i get this error

> Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at external/webkit/Source/WebCore/make-hash-tools.pl line 23.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/Source/WebCore/make-hash-tools.pl line 23.
>   make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/Source/WebCore/html/DocTypeStrings.cpp] Error 2
>   make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
>   Can't locate Switch.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at external/webkit/Source/WebCore/make-hash-tools.pl line 23.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at external/webkit/Source/WebCore/make-hash-tools.pl line 23.

so please can you help me

Comment: Same boat as you. It seems that, starting from perl 5.14 a component called "Switch.pm" has been removed from perl. I'm trying to downgrade perl or install a lower version, but I'm having some problems with brew (it spits a "No available formula for libswitch-perl" error message :(

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error as you.

just run:

sudo apt-get install libswitch-perl

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. To solve the issue, we need to install the Switch module for Perl. To install Perl modules, we can use cpan. You can search for more information on cpan, but the following worked for me:

```
sudo cpan -f Switch
```